# How to reverse a string of numbers in a nested loop

Tags: java

This is a homework question so I would like help, not an answer.

I'm trying to create 2 triangles out of numbers based on a number entered by the user.

```
"Enter a number between 2-9: "3"
1
12
123

  1
 21
321
```

IE2:

```
"Enter a number between 2-9: "5"
1
12
123
1234
12345

    1
   21
  321
 4321
54321
```

I have been able to get the first triangle complete. But when I add my nested loop it messes up my first triangle with the numbers developed from the nested loop. It also puts all the numbers in a straight vertical line. I've tried variations for different nest loops and even tried messing with a `StringBuilder`, but was still unsuccessful.
Here's what I have in code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NestedLoops
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a Number between 2-9: ");
        int width = input.nextInt();

        String r = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= width; i++)
        {
            r = r + i;
            System.out.println(r);

        }

    }

}
```

Again, I'm looking for help/understanding and not just an answer.

Comment: Please hover over the `homework` tag and read what it says there.

Comment: do you need to use a nested loop for the assignment? You can solve this in two loops without nesting them or even 1 with some more complicated string manipulation.

Comment: @Xymostech, can't use school. suggestions?

Comment: Thought of using printf ??

Comment: @RayCheng What do you mean?

Comment: Can you post the code for your second loop?

Comment: The code has to be a nested loop.

Comment: @RayCheng you want to see what I have tried?

Comment: @Xymostech, I tried to put `student` or `school` tag but after I save, it become `homework`.

Comment: @RayCheng I think the point is that you're not supposed to put tags like that at all. The questions should be no different depending on if they're homework or not. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: @SkyVar, if you post your code, others can help you better by following your thoughts.

Comment: @RayCheng my code is posted below the 2 output examples.

Comment: @Xymostech, I disagree. Questions need to be tagged properly. What harm does it do if it's tagged student? There could be someone looking for questions tagged as student and offer help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    int width = 5;
    // for all lines; number of lines = width
    for (int line = 1; line <= width; line++) {
        // print numbers from 1 to current line number  
        for (int n = 1; n <= line; n++) {
            System.out.print(n);
        }
        // end of line
        System.out.println();
    }
    // add empty line between triangles
    System.out.println();
    // for all lines; number of lines = width
    for (int line = 1; line <= width; line++) {
        // printing padding spaces, number of spaces = with - line number
        int nSpaces = width - line;
        for (int i = 0; i < nSpaces; i++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        // print numbers from number of current line to 1
        for (int n = line; n >= 1; n--) {
            System.out.print(n);
        }
        // end of line
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Please disregard my last comment, I didn't see where you set line back to 1 in the 2nd for loop.

Comment: this is Java rule: in for (int line = 1; line <= width; line++) {..}var line is visible only inside block {}. It is different from C++

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects the 2nd part of the question.

1. You need to generate strings with the numbers in the reverse order:

   - You could do this by adding the numbers at the other end.
   - You could do this by reversing the strings.
2. You need to arrange that there are spaces to the left.

   - You could do this by adding the required number of spaces to the left end of the string.
   - You could do this by using the System.out.format(...) with a template that right aligns the string in a field with the required number of characters.  (OK, that's a bit too obscure ...)

Or, you can build the string in a character array or string builder rather than using string concatenation.

The "trick" is to figure out what strategy you are going to use ... before you start cutting code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a queue.
eg. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Enque the numbers till you reach the max, and then start dequing them.

And while you dequeue, you need to apply the reverse

```
Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= width; i++)
        {
            r = r + i;
            q.add(r);
            System.out.println(r);

        }

        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            String j = q.remove();
             //reverse j
            System.out.println(reverse(j));
        }
```

I leave the reversing part for you to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add another loop after your first loop like

```
String r = "";
String space = "";
    for (int i = width; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        r = r + i;
        System.out.println(r);

    }
```

Try it. not yet tested

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int n = 5;

    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {            
        for (int j=(n*2), k=n; j>1; j--) 
        {
            if (k <= i) 
            {
                System.out.print(k);
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.out.print('*');
            }

            k += (j)-1 > n ? -1 : 1;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to implement in scala. Ignore if you don't like it..:-)

```
 class Triangle extends App
{
  val width = Console.readInt()

  if (width < 2 || width > 9)
  {
     throw new RuntimeException()
  }

  var i, j = 1;

  for (i <- 1 to width)
  {
     for (j <- 1 to i)
     {
        print(j)
     }
     print("\n")
  }

  for (i <- 1 to width)
  {
     for (dummy <- 1 to width-i)
     {
        print(" ")
     }
     for (j <- i to 1 by -1)
     {
       print(j)
     }
     print("\n")
  }
}
```